# DSBulk with ScyllaDB

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, scylla, dsbulk

I'm trying to use DSBulk to load data into ScyllaDB.  I know officially DSBulk doesn't support Scylla, but I found a post of someone using it instead of cqlsh.

When I'm trying to connect, I'm always getting this error `init query OPTIONS: error writing )`

Has anyone ever used it with Scylla and know how to fix that?

Here's the post: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201903.mbox/%3CCALrZ4T1wkpyKcinfo6N_pAPXyn-gkV2FbkkM3ot8XOUAKd4cUQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, interesting, worth to see the log on the scylla side and even to run wireshark with CQL plugin.
For upload, the spark migrator is a valid, tested option for Scylla

Comment: Spark migrator for Scylla is at https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-migrator
Slightly obsolete blog describing the migrator: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-migrator